# On npm install: Unhandled rejection Error: EACCES: permission denied

Tags: npm, permissions

I have managed to corrupt my `npm` install, and whenever I try to install packages using `npm install`, I receive error messages along these lines:

> Unhandled rejection Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/marknorgate/.npm/_cacache/tmp/a449402d'

I have tried reinstalling node & npm, and I have also tried to relocate my npm cache elsewhere using [these instructions](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions) but nothing works.

How can I get it working?

Answer (score 991, accepted):

Restore ownership of the user's npm related folders, to the current user, like this:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config
```

Comment: This worked for me after I tried 4-5 other things which didn't work: 1) --unsafe-perm, 2) upgrading npm, 3) restarting, 4) running with sudo, etc etc.

Comment: Same as @AlexYork for me. I saw my user and group already as the owner of those two but I guess a subdirectory or two had different owner(s). Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me :), before that I was trying this https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally. Not able to understand if its a same problem or different.

Comment: Looks like, at some point in my flailing with node, one of those cache directories was created with `root` ownership. This fixed up all up. Thank you!

Comment: for macOS and fish shell, replace those commands with: # sudo chown -R yourUser:staff ~/.npm and # sudo chown -R yourUser:staff ~/.config (replace yourUser with the response from the command # whoami )

Comment: this worked for me, thank you!
I tried to reinstall npm with a node version manager which recommended by npm but it didn't work!

Comment: None of the above fixed the problem for me. I did ls -al to make sure the user and group were set correctly. They are. Still getting permissions errors, even when trying to install with sudo. [EDIT: Ryu Kent's solution below solved the problem for me.]

Comment: Does npm expect these directories to belong to `$USER:$GROUP` after it is installed? If so, does anyone know what might change the permissions on these directories?

Answer (score 76):

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.config
```

Answer (score 48):

This happens if the first time you run NPM it's with sudo, for example when trying to do an npm install -g.

The cache folders need to be owned by the current user, not root.

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config
```

This will give ownership to the above folders when running with normal user permissions (not as sudo).

It's also worth noting that you shouldn't be installing global packages using SUDO. If you do run into issues with permissions, it's worth changing your global directory. The docs recommend:

`mkdir ~/.npm-global`

`npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'`

Then updating your PATH in wherever you define that (~/.profile etc.)

`export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH`

You'll then need to make sure the PATH env variable is set (restarting terminal or using the source command)

https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

Comment: Voting this up for the clear explanation as to why :)

Comment: Yup. This solved the problem for me when the "correct solution" above didn't.

Comment: All this stuff should be abstracted away by npm, but instead we have to deal with it manually. You'd think it would be high priority for the maintainers to fix things like this, but what do I know. Thanks for explaining *why* we need to do these commands!

Answer (score 12):

```
sudo npm cache clean --force --unsafe-perm
```

and then npm i goes normally

Answer (score 10):

Above answer didn't work for me. Just try to run your command with `--unsafe-perm`.

e.g

```
npm install -g node@latest --unsafe-perm
```

This seems to solve the problem.

Comment: @JenLim have you sorted out it or not?

Comment: I solved the problem by running the following in terminal: npm cache clear — force.

Answer (score 7):

If none of suggestions in answers worked out, try the following command: `npm cache clear --force`. It worked for me.

I found it at https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1809.

Answer (score 3):

change ownership

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config
```

worked for as i installed package using sudo

Answer (score 2):

just create folders `_cache/tmp` under `.npm` manually at location `/Users/marknorgate/.npm/_cacache/tmp` and run your command with administrator access

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

This was the one that worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Simply do `sudo npm cache clean --force --unsafe-perm` and `npm i` will go normally.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:
On the command line, in your home directory, create a directory for global installations:

```
mkdir ~/.npm-global
```

Configure npm to use the new directory path:

```
npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
```

In your preferred text editor, open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line:

```
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
```

On the command line, update your system variables:

```
source ~/.profile
```

Now use npm install it should work.

Comment: This is the modern and correct approach. Still seeing too many `sudo npm i -g` solutions in other questions akin to the infamous `sudo chown 777`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me!

[Resolving EACCES permissions errors when installing packages globally](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally)

Answer (score 0):

you can try following command for expo :

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.expo
```

Answer (score 0):

as per npm community

```
sudo npm cache clean --force --unsafe-perm
```

and then npm install goes normally.

source: [npm community-unhandled-rejection-error-eacces-permission-denied](https://npm.community/t/unhandled-rejection-error-eacces-permission-denied-angular-npm-install/4981)

Answer (score 0):

Simply run on terminal : `sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm`

This worked for me !!

Answer (score -3):

This one works for me:

```sh
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
```

I did not use the `-g` because I am the only user. I used a MacBook Air.

Answer (score -5):

sudo npm install -g @angular/cli

use this. it worked for me