# React App Suddenly Failing To Compile - scss unable to import

Tags: reactjs, sass, create-react-app

App was compiling last night when running `npm start`. This morning it's throwing this error:

Failed to Compile

```
./src/components/HamButton/styles.scss (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./src/components/HamButton/styles.scss)
To import Sass files, you first need to install node-sass.
Run `npm install node-sass` or `yarn add node-sass` inside your workspace.
```

Running `npm install node-sass` didn't fix it.

If I comment out all scss imports, app will compile however styles are not applied.

What's causing this and how can I fix it?

Thanks

Node v10.15.3
npm v6.4.1

Comment: after installing `node-sass`, have you restarted the app? If yes, what changed in the error?

Comment: my npm install was corrupt. After I fixed that, installing node-sass solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my npm install was corrupt so followed these steps: [On npm install: Unhandled rejection Error: EACCES: permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50639690/on-npm-install-unhandled-rejection-error-eacces-permission-denied)

Then installed node-sass and it worked.