# i am having issues with npm install express

Tags: node.js, express, npm-install

i am learning to use the express framework for nodeJs. i am having issues installing express using `npm install express --save`

```
Unhandled rejection Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/akandegeorge/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/37/92'

Unhandled rejection Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/akandegeorge/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/22/9a'

Unhandled rejection Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/akandegeorge/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/06/5a'

npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/akandegeorge/.npm/_logs/2019-08-18T18_13_54_120Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [on-npm-install-unhandled-rejection-error-eacces-permission-denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50639690/on-npm-install-unhandled-rejection-error-eacces-permission-denied)

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs on MacOS when the permissions on your home folder are wrong and are preventing npm from creating files on your disk. You can fix this by [resetting your home folder's permissions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203538).

Answer (score 0):

**Restore ownership of the user's npm related folders, to the current user, like this:**

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config
```

then  try

```
sudo npm install express --save
```