# Gatsby EACCES: permission denied

Tags: reactjs, redux, gatsby

I am using Gatsby for the first time and I cannot figure out this error. I have done tons of googling and nothing seems to work.

> warn Error persisting state: EACCES: permission denied, rename
>   '/mnt/d/projects/gatsby-starter-hello-world/.cache/redux' ->

I have reinstalled node, and gatsby cli and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50639690/on-npm-install-unhandled-rejection-error-eacces-permission-denied)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but taken [from the Github](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/21982):

> I'd opened VS Code from WSL which appears to lock some folders. By closing VS Code and then running gatsby build I was able to get everything working without having to downgrade or clear any folders.

So closing VSCode and running the gatsby command fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Even later to the party.

Running `gatsby clean` and/or closing VS Code did not solve it for me.

What did, was to manually delete the `.cache` folder in the gatsby project, then run `gatsby develop` again.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are in admin mode.

Another way to solve that issue is to use [sudo](https://www.sudo.ws/docs/man/1.8.28/sudo.man/#:%7E:text=sudo%20allows%20a%20permitted%20user,to%20query%20the%20security%20policy.) command and set the full permission for the project folder.

For instance,
`sudo chmod -R 777 gatsby-starter-hello-world/`

Or direct use the commands whatever you want to apply for.
`sudo npm install`

References: [https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/linux-file-permissions#:~:text=To%20change%20directory%20permissions%20for,only%20read%20permission%20for%20everyone](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/linux-file-permissions#:%7E:text=To%20change%20directory%20permissions%20for,only%20read%20permission%20for%20everyone).

https://www.cyberithub.com/best-ways-to-become-root-user-superuser-in-linux-rhel-centos-ubuntu/