# NPM `EACCES` error, not fixed by changing the default directory

Tags: npm, permissions

I was getting an EACCES error from NPM so I followed these directions to fix it by changing the default directory:  https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions  Using the test they gave at the end, I installed jshint globally without error.

However, when I try to build an Angular project

```
sudo ng new ProjectName --style=scss --routing
```

I get a lot of errors, the first one being

```
Unable to save binary /home/addem/Web/ExplainAngular/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-57 : { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/addem/Web/ExplainAngular/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
```

I then followed these instructions:  [Error: EACCES: permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38323880/error-eacces-permission-denied)

Still doesn't fix the problem, so at this point I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the cause.  I had installed the Angular CLI before I followed the fixes above, and therefore the Angular CLI did not have all the ... "stuff" it needed.  I guess maybe dependencies or packages.  Anyway, after doing the above fixes and then running

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

I can now create the project without errors.