# error An unexpected error occurred: "EACCES: permission denied

Tags: reactjs

I am getting an error while running `npm install` for a react application:

> An unexpected error occurred: "EACCES: permission denied, unlink
> '/home/ats/react-app/myapp/node_modules/@babel/helper-module-imports/LICENSE'".

Can someone help me sort this error out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: EACCES: permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38323880/error-eacces-permission-denied)

Comment: You need to provide permissions to your root folder. Which OS are you using?

Comment: iam currently using ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 42):

I had the same problem and I solved it like this:

- Remove `node_modules` folder of your project manually.
- Then `yarn install` or `npm install`.

Answer (score 10):

Try changing the folder permissions to have the correct ones. If you consider there is no drawback to have the folder with full permissions this command should solve your problem:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 folderName
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute as sudo if you are using Linux.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31449041)

Comment: On top of that, this is NOT a good thing to go unfortunately.