# Unable to download a npm module in Node.js v18.18.2

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, zeppos

I recently downloaded Node.js from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download) using the macOS installer. The installation went normal but was unable to download a npm module from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zeppos/zeus-cli?activeTab=readme). I ran this command in the terminal:

```
npm i @zeppos/zeus-cli -g
```

but kept getting EACCESS errors in the start. So, I unistalled Node.js by deleting all files and then reinstalling. After reinstalling and running the same command, but this time, I got another issue:

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@zeppos
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@zeppos'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@zeppos'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@zeppos'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/sambhav/.npm/_logs/2023-10-20T08_46_47_811Z-debug-0.log
```

This is the entire log I got. I also tried checking if it had installed and if all these logs were ignorable so I get outputting the version with `zeus -v` but it showed `zsh: command not found: zeus`

I tried to update the npm, reinstall my nodejs tried different versions, gave access to the user for sudo commands but I could not find any resolution to this.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=inFi-dEFnR0) is the video I referred for this.

Comment: Seems like it installed correctly, so you have an actual problem?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes. I tried to check if the module installed by checking its version but it says command not found

Comment: So why didn't you show that? What _exactly_ did you do? It's not globally installed, did you run it via npm run[-script] or npx?

Comment: @jonrsharpe its there in the question also. i used npm

Comment: You used npm _to install it_. Successfully, as far as we can tell. My question was: how did you get "command not found"? And we can now see that, despite not installing it globally, you assumed it would be globally installed. So: don't do that? Use scripts, or npx.

Comment: @jonrsharpe im sorry but i could not get what u meant. im really new to nord js and am unable to follow you

Comment: as pointed out in the above comment, install it globally if you expect to run it via terminal npm i -g @zeppos/zeus-cli

Comment: anyways i had a typo in the command and i changed it. It again shows EACCES issues. I saw many questions on stack overflow and tried a few answers but none worked.

Comment: @WTJ how do i install it globally? Sorry if its a silly question to ask but Im really new to this

Comment: @SambhavKhandelwal npm i -g @zeppos/zeus-cli

Comment: @WTJ yes i tried that now and got another issue. i have edited the question

Comment: The command you're running _is how_. It's not a typo, you're just doing a different thing. And given the message says it couldn't be installed, why try to find out if it was? _Which_ questions, which answers?

Comment: @jonrsharpe i tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52713928/error-an-unexpected-error-occurred-eacces-permission-denied and https://net2.com/how-to-fix-eacces-permission-denied/

Comment: Please [edit] the question, to say what _specifically_ you did. Given it's an error about file permissions, that says to fix the permissions or run as admin, and the answers on that question include how to do both of those things, it's hard to see what else you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, the comment section is abit too stuffy, here is what i believe you should do assuming you have no admin access

```
sudo npm install -g npx

npm i @zeppos/zeus-cli

#to run the command
npx zeus [param here]
```

(Edit: realised -g npx would most likely cause the same access error)

alternatively you could add your local node_modules to your path, can refer to this threads [How to use executables from a package installed locally in node_modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679932/how-to-use-executables-from-a-package-installed-locally-in-node-modules)

on the root folder of your project (where the node_modules reside), where you installed the zeus-cli, run the following command to temporarily add it to your path.
PATH is where your system will look for "zeus" binary.

```
export PATH="./node_modules/.bin:$PATH"
```

once you added the path, you can do a

```
which zeus
```

to confirm if the system can find it.

to make this permanent, you need to add it to your .profile or .zprofile so that you don't need to add it to your path everytime you login.

Comment: I tried your command of installing npx but i got the EACCESS issue

Comment: if you are able to sudo, can try using sudo

Comment: sudo does not work. `sambhav is not in the sudoers file`.

Comment: export PATH="./node_modules/.bin:$PATH"

afterward try running zeus

Comment: what is my $PATH supposed to be? Which path?

Comment: just updated the answer, take a look.

Comment: I ran `which zeus` and it said `zeus not found`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255687/discussion-between-wtj-and-sambhav-khandelwal).

Comment: I could not find the .zprofile file