# Can't run 'expo start' on a expo-react-native app, permission problem

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo, linux-mint

> Well, i see that already have many questions related to my problem on this site, but i also see that NONE of the solutions work for my specific case, because of that, i am opening that question, so **it is not a duplicate**.

### Context (environment)

- Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon
- Expo v32
- React-Native-Application
- GitHub Private Repository (from where i cloned the app)
- Node Latest LTS (v10.15.1)
- NPM v6.4.1
- /\ Both using NVM (Node Version Manager)

**package.json**

```
{
"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.0",
    "native-base": "^2.10.0",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-credit-card-input": "https://github.com/itspauloroberto/react-native-credit-card-input.git",
    "react-native-password-strength-meter": "https://github.com/itspauloroberto/react-native-password-strength-meter.git",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-scalable-image": "^0.5.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-form": "^8.1.0",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.2",
    "url-join": "^4.0.0",
    "vanilla-masker": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

### The Problem

My problem is when i try to run the following command `expo start` or `npm start` that is the same.

**I HARDLY BELIEVE THAT IS A OS PROBLEM** because last week i was using the same project on another os `elementary-os` and i had not any problems!

Then i get this error when i execute `expo start` or `npm start`:

```
Uncaught Error { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/itspauloroberto/.expo/state.json.354451305']
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/home/itspauloroberto/.expo/state.json.354451305' }
```

### How to reproduce it:

- Install/Use the OS Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon.
- Install [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) (node-version-manager)
- Install npm and node using `nvm install 10.15.1`
- Install expo-cli using `npm install expo-cli`
- Create a new expo react-native project using `expo init`.
- Try to run it using `expo start`.

### What i've tried

First of all, i have sure that this project/application runs ok, because i had another OS (elementaryOS) on last week and i was working on the project with no problems, also i have a team that works on it with no problems also.

- I tried to reinstall my `node` and `npm` and also the `expo-cli`.
- I tried to `rm -rf node_modules` and `npm install`.
- I tried to remove the `package.lock.json` and `npm install` again.
- I tried to set a global dir for npm global installs with permission as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49714908/2319589)
- I tried to install `nvm` node version manager, (and i am using it atm).
- I tried to `chown myuser project-folder` to give my user access to the folder (tried on .expo folder and node_modules folder also)
- I tried to `chmod 777 and 755 and 655` the whole project folder.
- I tried to run the `expo start`, `npm start` command with `sudo` prefix but sudo cannot find `expo` or neither `npm`.
- I tried to remove the repository and clone it using `git clone` again.
- And many, many, many other things. (also i did preys)
- Also there is no SELinux involvement as you can see below:

  > ls -ld
  >
  > drwxr-xr-x 2 itspauloroberto itspauloroberto 4096 Feb 20 14:54 .

Because of that i am creating this question, even if i see this error on many of the website none have my context.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### I found the problem!

**The main reason was because, in some moment, i used `sudo` to install something related to expo, then expo created some files that belongs to the `root` user in another directory that was not on the project folder that i am working.**

So it was because the initial files by expo on the very initial install of expo was installed using `sudo` apparently, because the files inside this directory: `home/itspauloroberto/.expo` and also the folder was owned by `root` (i checked it using `la -ls` command and saw `root` as the owner.) instead of my user `itspauloroberto` that was the main source of the error.

### To get rid of this error, do the following steps:

- navigate to the `home/your_user/` directory.
- delete the `.expo` folder using `sudo rm -rf .expo` (sudo needed because the folder owner is root)
- run again expo using `expo start`

If you find any additional errors related to some directory or file, navigate to the file/directory that is on the error message and delete it. Because it should belong to `root` user also.

Comment: Thanks for saving me a giant headache. I was so confused why I had to keep changing the permissions of all these generated expo files from root to my user. I would've been chmoding forever.

Comment: just brilliant bro...

Answer (score 1):

I had  this issue because I had been working with `cmd` locally, and bash in an Ubuntu WSL2 sub-system.

I must have installed some packages from the ubuntu terminal, so besides for deleting a `.expo` file from my WSL home directory, I had to delete my `node_modules` file, and run `npm install` from my windows-cmd console.

Answer (score 0):

uninstall expo first. then uninstall npm and reinstall npm and then expo

Answer (score 0):

Often when you see an error like :

Uncaught Error Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/r/.expo/state.json.728296139'

you can try running the command again except with sudo in front of it.

For example, the error below:

```
expo init my-app
Uncaught Error Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/r/.expo/state.json.728296139'
```

Can be solved with:

```
$ sudo expo init my-app
Password:
```

Comment: Running with `sudo` is _not_ recommended. See the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54794579/13138364) for how to fix the underlying issue.