# JEST error EACCES: permission denied, mkdir

Tags: linux, testing, jestjs, node.js-fs

I'm working on a Typescript Rest API with Express, that I run on a linux machine, and in one of my middleware in charge of uploading files, I create a folder in the public folder with a specific ID as a name.

It's working all fine until I run my tests with jest where I got this error :

`EACCES: permission denied, mkdir './public/uploads/jobCVs/639c396892d8bf249f9c98c7'`

From :

```
      22 |         const folderPath = `./public/uploads/jobCVs/${req.params.jobId.toString()}`;
    > 23 |         fs.mkdirSync(folderPath, { recursive: true });
```

This fs.mkdir right here.

I don't get why it is blocked just during my tests... and anyone know how to get the permission to allow the mkdir call even when running tests with jests ?

I tried solutions from this stackoverflow question : [Error: EACCES: permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38323880/error-eacces-permission-denied) but still got the same error...

EDIT
I'm working inside a Docker container, and launching the test command inside it resolved all access problems. I can do this like this but still don't get why it doesn't work locally (outside docker).

Comment: use `path.resolve(folderPath)` to check what the absolute path `folderpath` resolves to. Maybe there is some mixup with the current working directory when running via jest versus running in debug?

Comment: Thanks, this gave me to think that locally my project folder is in my user folder and I don't know why jest doesn't get the root access to call the mkdir. But then, since my app is in a Docker container, I tested to launch my tests inside the container, and everything went fine !

Comment: Have you tried in a shell session this command : `mkdir './public/uploads/jobCVs/639c396892d8bf249f9c98c7'` to see if it's successful ?

Comment: @Philippe I got permission denied too ! Is it a problem with my global Linux User permission you think ?

Comment: Run this and post result : `ls -ld ./public/uploads/jobCVs; id`

Comment: @Philippe this is what I get 

kwitz@kevin-ThinkPad:~/code/jobsuccess/kitdocker/kitback$ ls -ld ./public/uploads/jobCVs; id
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 déc.  16 10:52 ./public/uploads/jobCVs
uid=1000(kwitz) gid=1000(kwitz) groups=1000(kwitz),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),122(lpadmin),134(lxd),135(sambashare),999(docker)

Comment: You can see `jobCVs` is owned by root. You can sudo to root, and run this command  `chown kwitz:kwitz ./public/uploads/jobCVs`.