# Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename. Using WSL

Tags: node.js, next.js, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nvm, turborepo

I am creating next app using turborepo on wsl. But got below error
[image]

I tried fixing it using
[Error: EACCES: permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38323880/error-eacces-permission-denied) but it did not work.

when I am running `npx create-next-app@latest` in home directory its working fine

Comment: Just add `sudo` before the command.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of Pages, we have to use app router.
Create a new directory. Select app router yes. It is recommended.
Or do rename the directory
Run this command
cd finalw
mkdir src
mv pages src/pages
This have worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).