# aws-cdk: cdk deploy failed with Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am trying to deploy CloudFormation templates using CDK
But receive an Error EACCES: permission denied, scandir

```
node:fs:1527
  handleErrorFromBinding(ctx);
  ^
Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir 'C:/Users/Phat/Desktop/workspace/resize-image-service/cdk.out/asset.a4d282274929658deaa9944f80a716703650e903f801727100f56ab94049e35a/nodejs/node_modules/.bin/prebuild-install'
    at Object.readdirSync (node:fs:1527:3)
    at GlobSync._readdir (\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:431:848900)
    at GlobSync._readdirInGlobStar (\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:431:848291)        
    at GlobSync._readdir (\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:431:848723)
    at GlobSync._processGlobStar (\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:431:849803)
    at GlobSync._process (\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:431:846756)
    at GlobSync._processGlobStar (\npm\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:431:850312)
    at GlobSync._process (\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:431:846756)
    at GlobSync._processGlobStar (\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:431:850312)
    at GlobSync._process (\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:431:846756) {
  errno: -4092,
  syscall: 'scandir',
  code: 'EACCES',
  path: 'Desktop/workspace/resize-image-service/cdk.out/asset.a4d282274929658deaa9944f80a716703650e903f801727100f56ab94049e35a/nodejs/node_modules/.bin/prebuild-install'
}
```

CDK CLI Version
2.102.0

Framework Version
No response

Node.js Version
v18.18.2

OS
Window 10 Pro x64

Language
TypeScript

Language Version
typescript@4.9.5

i want to pass permission and deploy successful

Comment: This is not an AWS issue but node. The error is clear that it doesn't have permission access to the `node_module` directory.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38323880/error-eacces-permission-denied for similar issue.

Comment: thank @Tsal Troser i resolved this in macos but still stuck in window

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue with CDK on windows when I have deployed previously in another session with the same CDK and then returned to it later. One option that may work is to just delete the node_modules folder on that problematic path and try again with cdk deploy. It will repopulate the necessary node modules but the permissions should now be correct for your current user.